# Trouble with MS Access Query

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I am using MS Access 2007 along with a C# application. Following is the query that I'm currently using. This query is working fine:

```
string qry = "Select sum(InvoiceAmount) as InvAmt, InvoiceDate From Invoices Group By InvoiceDate Having (InvoiceDate between #"+previousPaymentDate+"# and #"+currentPayDate+"#)";
```

The above query is returning the sum of invoice amounts group by invoice date.

There are some invoices generated due to cheque bounce. i.e. say 25000/- is the invoice amount for cheque bounce. I have marked this invoice using "ChequeBounced" boolean field. Is there any way to include this clause within above query. I want this query somewhat like this -

```
 string qry = "Select sum(InvoiceAmount) as InvAmt, InvoiceDate From Invoices Group By InvoiceDate Having (InvoiceDate between #"+previousPaymentDate+"# and #"+currentPayDate+"#) and ChequeBounced='False'";
```

Thanks for sharing your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT InvoiceDate, Sum(InvoiceAmount) AS InvAmount
FROM Invoices
WHERE ChequeBounced=False
GROUP BY InvoiceDate
HAVING (InvoiceDate between #"+previousPaymentDate+"# and #"+currentPayDate+"#)
```

I have not laid out the SQL with quotes for clarity. Note that False is a built-in constant equal to zero in Access and should not be quoted for boolean fields. It would be best to ensure that your dates are in the format yyyy/mm/dd, or you may get unexpected results.

Comment: Dates are not stored in a format. You only need to worry about that when using a string format to represent a date value. In the criteria you aren't limited to ISO format -- you can use any unambiguous data format.